# How I can show soft keyboard on canvas and write on it in android

Tags: android

I am trying to write on the canvas by the soft keyboard in android.

My question is how can I show soft keyboard and handle events it generate on the canvas.
My code is :

```
public class DrawView extends View {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            private static final String LOGID = "MxView";
            String message = "No key pressed yet.";
            DrawView(Context context) {
                    super(context);
                    setFocusable(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                    canvas.drawText(message, 5, 20, paint);

            }
            @Override
            public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent ev) {
                    switch(keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                            message = "Key is Enter!";
                            Log.i(LOGID, message);
                            break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E:
                            message = "Key is E!";
                            Log.i(LOGID, message);
                            break;
                    default:
                            return false;
                    }
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can probably do this by providing "Menu" to your screen. When user select that option, do following actions.

- Allow user to touch screen, this is the place he want to place his text
- Then create a "Custom Dialog" which takes input from user as you want.
- Return those text to your screen and write text where user touched.

Second way is to view soft keyboard by following code.

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

This will show you soft keyboard, and to take argument from keyboard, use following code.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    Log.d("TEST", "Key Down  :" + keyCode + " String : " + s);
    s += (char) event.getUnicodeChar();

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Here, "s" is String object which store pressed values.

To hide keyboard,

```
((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
                .hideSoftInputFromWindow(rel.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Here, `rel` is `RelativeLayout`. You can pass any view here.

Comment: what is rel at rel.getWindowToken() ?

Comment: @support_ms, hi i edited my answer. Please check. :)